# Convolutional Net for signature recognition is training but doesn't converge

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

My model is training and is not predicting the same output everytime but it is not converging, I mean in the 30th epoch the validation accuracy = 65% and, in the 31st, the validation accuracy = 38%, for example. Also, the loss is around 27 to 29 and is not decreasing at all (while fitting the model).

Just for introduction:

Problem: Recognizing if a signature is genuine or forgery.

Dataset: GPDS database offline signature which consists of 4000 users => 24 genuine / 30 forgery per user.

Input of the net: The sum of two signature images of the same user. Genuine + Forgery = False (class 0) or Genuine + Genuine = True (class 1) .

Now, Im training with around 130k images (just a small part of the approximately 4 million possible sum images) which 100k are Genuine+Forgery and 30k are Genuine+Genuine from around 150 users in total. Anyway, Im using class weights in training (model.fit_generator).

There is one concern about the problem:

The size of the images varies but normally it is around 1200x400 pixels. It is huge for the memory and the training lasts a looong time so I used the attribute target_size of the function flow_from_directory which resizes the image to 100x100 pixels. Also, Im training for the maximum of 100 epochs.

Im using an instance in Amazon with 1 GPU, 8 CPUs, 15Gb RAM,

The code is below:

---

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, shear_range=0.2, 
zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\DL\TrainGenuineForgery', target_size=(100, 100), color_mode="grayscale", batch_size=10, class_mode='binary')

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory('C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\DL\Validation', target_size=(100, 100), color_mode="grayscale", batch_size=10, class_mode='binary')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(96, (11, 11), input_shape=(1, 100, 100), activation='relu', data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(384, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

optAdadelta = keras.optimizers.Adadelta(lr=1.0, rho=0.95, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optAdadelta, metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=13000, epochs=100, validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=100, class_weight = {0:29,1:71})
```

---

I would like to know if the image resizing can be a serious problem, maybe training not enough, maybe the approach of the solution is not good, maybe not enough dataset samples, maybe not adequate optimizer.

Thanks for your attention!

Lucas

Comment: Compare the "training accuracy" with the "validation accuracy". If there is a big gap, your model is too good (something called "overfitting"). In this case, increasing dropouts, or reducing the amount of filters/layers, etc., might help. If both are bad, then it's probable that your model is not powerful enough or not suited for the task. PS: I think "categorical_crossentropy" is more suited to "softmax" than "sparse_categorical_crossentropy".

Comment: Hey Daniel. Thanks for your reply. The validation accuracy is bad and fluctuating while the training accuracy is pretty good (around 95%) and increasing. Probably it is a problem of overfitting. Do you know how should I try to solve it??

Comment: How do I know the amount of filters/layers for my problem? And the dropouts, how do I know a good rate for them and where in my net should I put them?

Comment: There is no simple or ready answer for that. Mostly you have to try and adjust. I think the amount of filters in the convolutional layers and units in the dense layer are the most evident in your model. -- The dropouts can be layers (there is one in your model, with 20% of dropout), you can probably put one after each convolution, for instance.

Comment: Also, make sure the training images and the test images are similar somehow, if they have an evident difference, your model will probably catch that difference.

Comment: Of course, the more data you have, less overfitting too. If you train with more examples that should improve.